# committed use discount for gke nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created GKE using terraform with custom machine type custom-6-20480. I want to create committed use discount for the CPU and memory that I'm using for nodes. I know that the machine type indicates I am using 6CPU and 20GB memory but I can't see the machine series type which N1 or N2. I tried looking up to the console and ran "gcloud container node-pools describe node-pool-name --cluster cluster-name", but these are only showing the machine type as custom-6-20480, not series. How to know which series I'm using on gke-node-pool?
To create committed use discount I need to select the Commitment type which is N1 or N2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the series of machines by following the steps below.

1. Navigate to Compute engine, click on VM instances.
2. You can see the nodes of your cluster present there with their names starting with the cluster's name.
3. Click on any of them for details and you can see the series of machine under the header ‘machine type’.

Comment: I have tried it, but even there its only showing as
Machine type
custom (6 vCPUs, 20 GB memory)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the type. I went to billing -> commitment analysis, where I can see what are resources are running under each commitment type.